# Travis CI failing when trying to test Golang HTTP Server

Tags: go, travis-ci

I'm very new to travis and Go. I have a test for a https server and it runs fine with I run `go test -v ./...` on my local machine but it will fail most of the time on Travis due to a `getsocketopt: connection refused` error when trying to connect to the server. It should be listening on `https://localhost:8081`. Is there something in my `.travis.yml` I can do to prevent this from happening?

Here is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: go
go:
 - 1.6
 - tip
matrix:
  allow_failures:
 - go: tip
before_install:
 - go get -v github.com/golang/lint/golint
install:
 - go get -v -d -t ./...
```

Here's my server creation code:

```
func (webserver *WebServer) Start(keyLocation string, certLocation string) <-chan error {
    errors := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        defer close(errors)
        errors <- http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", webserver.config.WebServerPort), certLocation, keyLocation, nil)
    }()
    return errors
}
```

And the client code:

```
func createHTTPClient(t *testing.T) *http.Client {
    t.Log("Creating a test client...")
    tr := &http.Transport {
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config {InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    t.Log("Created a test client")
    return &http.Client {Transport: tr}
}
```

Sample request with client

```
request, _ := http.NewRequest(httpmethod, fmt.Sprintf("https://localhost:%d/token", port), nil)
client.Do(request)
```

Sample starting the server in a test

```
errors := server.Start(testKeyLocation, testCertLocation)
//Handle errors from server
go func() {
    select {
        case err := <-errors:
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("Error with server: %s", err.Error())
            }
    }
}()
```

Comment: Are you checking the error when you try to start your server?

Comment: Yes, it's set to fail the test on any error produced from the go `http.ListenAndServeTLS` command. Though the failure is happening when I create a test client to try and connect to the server.

Comment: You need to show how you're creating the server and client first. This doesn't necessarily have anything to do with travis.

Comment: Added code samples for client and sever.

Comment: You have nothing synchronizing the start of your server. You're not showing where you call Start, but there's no guarantee that the server is listening at any point after. (You should also be using an httptest.Server which handles binding a random port and tls certs for you)

Comment: Sorry about that added the code I have in my test for  starting a server. So I looked at the httptest.Server but I'm trying to test a server I built how would using the httptest.Server class help?

Comment: The httptest.Server won't fix this problem, it's just better suited for tests. A good first guess is that you're trying to connect before the server is listening. Put a long sleep between starting the server and executing the tests to check. If that works, fix your synchronization (well, you should fix that anyway, but this will confirm it's the root cause).

Comment: (also your server error handling is in another goroutine without synchronization, so it's entirely possible that the server fails, but the client's failure is reported first)

Comment: Ok so the sleep fixed my travis problem. This might be a novice question but how would you suggest I go about fixing the synchronization issues you mentioned? (Also would you mind adding the sleep suggestion as the answer so I can accept it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no synchronization between starting the server and trying to connect. Adding a `time.Sleep` after starting the server should highlight the issue.

One way to reduce the window where the server isn't ready is to create the `net.Listener` synchronously, and then add the open listener to the `http.Server` config before starting the server. The [`httptest.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) can do this for you, as well as bind to random ports to prevent conflicts during tests, and using local test TLS certificates.